# In a text file, count lines from string 'foo' to first empty line afterwards. Raise exception if 'foo' not found

Tags: python, file-io, python-polars, text-parsing

**Background**: I want to read some data from a text file, into a `polars` dataframe. The data starts at the line containing the string `foo`, and stops at the first empty line afterwards. Example file `test.txt`:

```
stuff to skip
more stuff to skip


skip me too

foo bar foobar
1   2   A
4   5   B
7   8   C


other stuff
stuff
```

`pl.read_csv` has args `skip_rows` and `n_rows`. Thus, if I can find the line number of `foo` and the line number of the first empty line afterwards, I should be able to read the data into a `polars` dataframe. How can I do that? I'm able to find `skip_rows`:

```
from pathlib import Path

file_path = Path('test.txt')

with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
    skip_rows = 0
    n_rows = 0
    for line_number, line in enumerate(file, 1):
        if 'foo' in line:
            skip_rows = line_number - 1
```

But how can I find also `n_rows` without scanning the file again? Also, the solution must handle the case when there's no line containing `foo`, e.g.

```
stuff to skip
more stuff to skip


skip me too

1   2   A
4   5   B
7   8   C


other stuff
stuff
```

In that case, I would like to either return a value indicating that `foo` was not found, or raise an exception so that the caller knows something went wrong (maybe a `ValueError` exception?).

**EDIT**: I forgot an edge case. Sometimes the data may continue until the end of the file:

```
stuff to skip
more stuff to skip


skip me too

foo bar foobar
1   2   A
4   5   B
7   8   C
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```py
start, end = None, None
with open("your_file.txt", "r") as f_in:
    for line_no, line in enumerate(map(str.strip, f_in)):
        if line.startswith("foo"):  # or use `if "foo" in line:`
            start = line_no
        elif start is not None and line == "":
            end = line_no
            break
    else:
        # no break, but we found `foo`
        if start is not None:
            end = line_no
        else:
            print("foo not found!")

if start is not None:
    print(f"{start=} {end=}")
```

Prints (with the first input from your question):

```
start=6 end=10
```

Comment: "The data starts at the line containing the string foo" - it doesn't say anything about specifically starting with "foo". Also what if all of the data is at the end of the file, and there is no empty line? Your example will claim foo wasn't found.

Comment: `if 'food network'.startswith("foo"):` also `if "foo" in "foot fetish":` ~ you see the problems?

Comment: @OysterShucker That I leave to OP - he/she can use regular expression, str.split etc. (if needed)

Comment: But your answer is in competition with mine, and mine handles all of the issues that you "leave to the OP". That's an affront to yourself. You spent time on this, but it's not competing for the reward. I'm not trying to badger you.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible solution. This solution covers some edge cases.

1. it will not find "foo" in "foobar"
2. it will find "Foo", "fOO", "FOO", etc
3. it stops at the first empty line or the end of the file, whichever is first

```py
try:
    with open('test.txt', 'r') as lines:
        for row, line in enumerate(lines):
            # maybe "foo" is present but mixed or uppercase
            # split on space so we find exactly "foo" and not "foo" in "footage"
            if 'foo' in line.lower().split(' '):
                for n_row, ln in enumerate(lines, row+1):
                    if not ln.strip(): 
                        break
                else:
                    # end of file, this line doesn't actually exist
                    # which is fine if you use this number for `stop` with range or splice
                    n_row += 1
                break
        else:
            raise Exception
except:
    print("foo was not found")
else:
    print(row, n_row) #6, 10
```

You may want to consider that, getting row numbers will likely mean that you need to go over the data a second time. With very little modification you can simply get the data, and still get the row numbers.

```py
try:
    with open('test.txt', 'r') as lines:
        for row, line in enumerate(lines):
            if 'foo' in line.lower().split(' '):
                data = [line.strip()]
                for n_row, ln in enumerate(lines, row+1):
                    if not (line := ln.strip()): 
                        break
                    data.append(line)
                else:
                    n_row += 1
                break
        else:
            raise Exception
except:
    print("foo was not found")
else:
    print(row, n_row)
    print(*data, sep='\n')
```

###### output

```
6 10
foo bar foobar
1   2   A
4   5   B
7   8   C
```

Here's a version that skips all the row humbug and gets straight to parsing the data, and turning it into a dataframe.

```
import polars
from io import StringIO

try:
    with open('test.txt', 'r') as lines:
        for line in lines:
            if 'foo' in line.lower().split(' '):
                data = line
                for ln in lines:
                    if not ln.strip(): break
                    data += ln
                break
        else:
            raise Exception
except:
    print("foo was not found")
else:
    print(polars.read_csv(StringIO(data)))
```

###### output

```
shape: (3, 1)
┌────────────────┐
│ foo bar foobar │
│ ---            │
│ str            │
╞════════════════╡
│ 1   2   A      │
│ 4   5   B      │
│ 7   8   C      │
└────────────────┘
```

Comment: I don't understand this line: `if not (line := ln.strip()):`. Why did you change it from `if not ln.strip():` ?

Comment: @DeltaIV - because in my first one we weren't saving the line. In my second one we are saving the line.  I assign the stripped line to a variable (`line`) so I don't have to strip it again to save a stripped version. The walrus (`:=`) allows me to assign a variable and have the condition, all in one line.

Comment: @DeltaIV - I updated my answer with a version that simply gets the data and turns it into a dataframe.

Answer (score 2):

[`next()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#iterators) with a [Generator Expression](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions) can be a useful pattern for this.

If no value is produced then `next()` will raise a `StopIteration` exception which you can catch and report to the caller.

```py
with open("test.txt") as f:
    f = enumerate(f)
    
    try: 
        skip_rows = next(n for n, line in f if "foo" in line)
        
    except StopIteration:
        raise ValueError("Start line not found.")
        
    for n, line in f:
        if line.strip() == "":
            n -= 1
            break
            
    n_rows = n - skip_rows
    
    print(f"{skip_rows=}")
    print(f"{n_rows=}")
```

```py
skip_rows=6
n_rows=3
```

Comment: Interesting! But I was imprecise - it's ok if the data go until the end of the text file. In other words, I don't think  `ValueError("End line not found.")` is needed. Can you modify your answer so that it works also when the data section continues until the end of the file? I added a relevant test case to the question.

Comment: Ah okay. In that case, `next()` can only be used for the start line condition. I've edited the answer but it's probably not as useful anymore compared to just the regular for loop approach.

Answer (score 2):

Here are two all polars solutions where each relies on the fixed length delimination to distinguish what is data or not.

### Scan for everything approach

```
csv_scan = (
    pl.scan_csv("ex.txt", 
                separator="\0", # null character as sep so just one column
                has_header=False, 
                schema={"a": pl.String} # name column here
                )
    .filter(pl.col('a').is_not_null()) 
)


dfdata = (
    csv_scan
    # this is kind of like a row id but only increments at unique values
    .group_by(z=pl.col("a").str.len_chars().rle_id(), maintain_order=True)
    .agg("a", len=pl.len())
    # Assume that data rows have the same string length, that the data
    # rows will be continuous, and that the meta rows won't have as many
    # same str length rows in a row as the data
    .with_columns(z1=pl.col("z").filter(pl.col("len").max() == pl.col("len")))
    .filter(
        (pl.col("z") == pl.col('z1'))
        | (pl.col("z") + 1 == pl.col('z1'))
    )
    # extract all based on \S regex, can't use extract_groups b/c we
    # don't know how many proper columns there are
    .select(
        pl.col("a")
        .explode()
        .str.extract_all(r"(\S)+")
        .list.to_struct()
    )
    .unnest("a")
    .collect()
    .pipe(
        lambda df: (
            # promote 0th row to header and discard it from data itself
            df[1:].rename(
                {f"field_{x}": y 
                 for x, y in enumerate(next(df.iter_rows()))})
        )
    )
    # TODO: cast columns to intended datatypes (see below)
)
```

### Scan for offsets approach then reread

```
csv_scan = pl.scan_csv(
    "ex.txt",
    separator="\0",  # null character as sep so just one column
    has_header=False,
    schema={"a": pl.String},  # name column here
)

offsets = (
    csv_scan.with_columns(i=pl.int_range(pl.len()))
    .group_by(z=pl.col("a").str.len_chars().rle_id(), maintain_order=True)
    .agg("a", "i", len=pl.len())
    .filter(
        (pl.col("z") == pl.col("z").filter(pl.col("len").max() == pl.col("len")))
        | (pl.col("z") + 1 == pl.col("z").filter(pl.col("len").max() == pl.col("len")))
    )
    .collect()
)

df = pl.read_csv(
    "ex.txt",
    skip_rows=offsets["i"][0][0] + 1,
    has_header=False,
    separator=" ",
    n_rows=offsets["len"][-1],
).pipe(lambda df: (
    df.select(
        df.melt()
        .filter(pl.col('value').is_not_null())
        .get_column('variable')
        .unique(maintain_order=True)
        .to_list()
        )
))
df.columns=offsets['a'][0].str.replace_all("(\s+)", " ").str.split(" ")[0]
```

The second approach would have the benefit that `read_csv` can infer the data types but when I run it, the foo column is still being inferred as strings maybe the first approach is best with manual dtype casting.

### Try to cast strings to numerics

```
for col in dfdata.columns:
    try:
        dfdata=dfdata.with_columns(pl.col(col).cast(pl.Int64))
        continue
    except:
        pass
    try:
        dfdata=dfdata.with_columns(pl.col(col).cast(pl.Float64))
        continue
    except:
        pass
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple approach:

1. read the csv as a one-column csv file
2. use Polars string matching to find the offsets
3. use `write_csv` to write the correct `slice` of the dataframe to a `StringIO` buffer
4. use `read_csv` with the `StringIO` buffer as the source to parse your csv as needed.

```py
def read_received_csv(path_to_file: str) -> DataFrame | None:
    """
    Read CSV file from the first occurrence of 'foo' until the next blank line or end of file.

    If 'foo' is not found, return None.
    """
    df_initial_read = pl.read_csv(
        path_to_file,
        has_header=False,
        separator="\0",  # no separator
        row_index_name="index",
        missing_utf8_is_empty_string=True,
        new_columns=["index", "unparsed_string"],
    )

    # Find the offset of the first occurrence of "foo".
    df_foo = df_initial_read.filter(pl.col("unparsed_string").str.contains(r"foo"))
    if df_foo.is_empty():
        return None

    slice_offset = df_foo.get_column("index").item(0)

    # Starting with the offset above, find the first blank line that follows "foo", if any
    df_next_blank = df_initial_read.slice(slice_offset).filter(
        pl.col("unparsed_string").str.strip_chars() == ""
    )

    if df_next_blank.is_empty():
        slice_length = None
    else:
        slice_length = df_next_blank.get_column("index").item(0) - slice_offset

    # Take a "slice" of the initial unparsed csv, write it out to a string buffer, and then
    # allow Polars to parse the string buffer per usual.
    return pl.read_csv(
        StringIO(
            df_initial_read.select("unparsed_string")
            .slice(slice_offset, slice_length)
            .write_csv(include_header=False)
        ),
        separator="\t",
    )
```

For your three cases above, this returns:
(with `foo` and a blank line, and assuming the tab character as your delimiter):

```
>>> read_received_csv("data/raw/so_78196632/test1.txt")
shape: (3, 3)
 foo  bar  foobar 
 ---  ---  ---    
 i64  i64  str    
 1    2    A      
 4    5    B      
 7    8    C
```

(no occurrence of `foo`)

```
>>> read_received_csv("data/raw/so_78196632/test2.txt")
```

(`foo` occurs, but no blank line follows it)

```
>>> read_received_csv("data/raw/so_78196632/test3.txt")
shape: (3, 3)
 foo  bar  foobar 
 ---  ---  ---    
 i64  i64  str    
 1    2    A      
 4    5    B      
 7    8    C
```

It's a relatively simple approach.  Perhaps not appropriate for very large files (as it reads the entire contents of the file into RAM).